# Struggling to convert onclick to onmouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is a working snippet for onclick. When you move the slider, then click calculate, it does the calculation I wish for.

Rather than clicking "calculate", I want the calculator to generate in real-time.

I've tried:

```
$('#calc').keyup(function() {
```

and

```
$('#calc').onmouseover(function() {
```

Pretty sure I'm missing something obvious here. Could someone put me out of my misery? :-)

```js
        var slider = document.getElementById("a");
        var output = document.getElementById("demo");
        output.innerHTML = slider.value;

        slider.oninput = function() {
            output.innerHTML = this.value;
        }
        
        
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#calc').on('click', function() {
                var amount = 0.225;
                var HowMany = $('#a').val();
                if (HowMany > 500)
                    amount = 0.1883;                
                if (HowMany > 700)
                    amount = 0.1483;
                if (HowMany > 1000)
                    amount = 0.125;
                $('#total').val(calc(HowMany, amount).toFixed(2));
            });



            function calc(h, m) {
                return (h * m);
            };

        });
```

```css
        .slider {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 15px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background: #d3d3d3;
            outline: none;
            opacity: 0.7;
            -webkit-transition: .2s;
            transition: opacity .2s;
        }

        .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: #4CAF50;
            cursor: pointer;
            
        }

        .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: #4CAF50;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="500" max="3000" value="500" step="100" class="slider" id="a">
    </div>




    Answer: <input type="text" id="total" size=5 maxlength=40>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calc">
```

Comment: I would do it using the `change` event of the range, but that's me...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sorry, tad confused. Not the best at JS /jQ. Could you give an example?

Comment: @HereticMonkey, very detailed and went out the way to make it super clean. Works a treat :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use the "change" event on the "slider". Then your value would change after it registers a change (in this case, when you mouse up after dragging the thumb).

I've added some comments in the code to note some changes I've made, and an alternate approach.

```js
// I find it's best to use jQuery for everything or nothing. 
// In this case, I've moved the code that was here into the 
// jQuery below.

$(document).ready(function() {

  var slider = $("#a");
  var output = $("#demo");
  output.html(slider.val());

  slider.on('input', function() {
    output.html(this.value);
  });

  // you could use 'input' here as well, but if the calculation
  // is actually more complicated, it's best not to do it "live".
  slider.on('change', function() {
    var amount = 0.225;
    var HowMany = $('#a').val();
    if (HowMany > 500)
      amount = 0.1883;
    if (HowMany > 700)
      amount = 0.1483;
    if (HowMany > 1000)
      amount = 0.125;
    $('#total').val(calc(HowMany, amount).toFixed(2));
  });



  function calc(h, m) {
    return (h * m);
  };

});
```

```css
.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="500" max="3000" value="500" step="100" class="slider" id="a">
</div>

Answer: <input type="text" id="total" size=5 maxlength=40>
<input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calc">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input).

Basically, replace this:

```
$('#calc').on('click', function() {
```

With this:

```
$('#a').on('input', function () {
```

And it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the calculation code in the button click event and not anywhere else. You can call this event handler in slider `oninput` handler:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("a");
        var output = document.getElementById("demo");
        output.innerHTML = slider.value;

        slider.oninput = function() {
            output.innerHTML = this.value;
            $('#calc').click();
        }
        
        
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#calc').on('click', function() {
                var amount = 0.225;
                var HowMany = $('#a').val();
                if (HowMany > 500)
                    amount = 0.1883;                
                if (HowMany > 700)
                    amount = 0.1483;
                if (HowMany > 1000)
                    amount = 0.125;
                $('#total').val(calc(HowMany, amount).toFixed(2));
            });



            function calc(h, m) {
                return (h * m);
            };

        });
```

```css
.slider {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 15px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background: #d3d3d3;
            outline: none;
            opacity: 0.7;
            -webkit-transition: .2s;
            transition: opacity .2s;
        }

        .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: #4CAF50;
            cursor: pointer;
            
        }

        .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: #4CAF50;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="500" max="3000" value="500" step="100" class="slider" id="a">
    </div>




    Answer: <input type="text" id="total" size=5 maxlength=40>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calc">
```